# Set permissions for future folders and files

Tags: 14.04, permissions, chmod, acl

I have some trouble managing permits in a folder and relative sub folders.

- I am working on ubuntu 14.04.
- I have a software which periodically creates new folders and files inside of a main folder.

For example I have the main folder `/media/Folder` and the software create the folder /media/Folder/First_Folder. When it creates the new folder, this one has no permits to write for the group and for other users. Here the output of the `ls -al` command: `drwxr-xr-x`. The software also creates other folders inside of the previous one, for example `/media/Folder/First_Folder/Second_Folder1` , `/media/Folder/First_Folder/Second_Folder2`, and so on.

I need to have full permits in all the subfolders and files, also the newly generated. I tried changing the permits recursively with the command: `sudo chmod 777 -R /media/Folder` but when new folders are created those have no permits again. 
After this i tried modifying the ACLs but i'm not really confident with these. Here's my `getfacl` screen:

```
file: Folder/
# owner: ubuntu
# group: ubuntu
# user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

As you can see my owner and group are ubuntu:ubuntu.
Then i try to chenge the ACL using the command:

```
sudo setfacl -Rdm g:ubuntu:rwx /media/Folder/
```

and now the screen become this:

```
# file: Folder/
# owner: ubuntu
# group: ubuntu
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:ubuntu:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::rwx
```

which looks good. But if i create a new folder inside of it the getfacl screen is:

```
# file: Folder//First_Folder
# owner: ubuntu
# group: ubuntu
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:ubuntu:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:ubuntu:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::rwx
```

As you can see the line with 5 and 8 it miss the write permit. How can i have always all permits ? I mean also for the future folders and files.

PS I tried also launching the commands: `sudo setfacl -Rdm o::rwx /media/Sources/Previsioni/` and `sudo setfacl -Rdm g::rwx /media/Sources/Previsioni/`.

Here's my etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=9deb0e4a-b93e-4cc6-8bda-c41f5e9244c7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=88be1282-e36e-49d4-820a-d05345addf5d none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0

//master/Triple_RDF  /media/Folder cifs credentials=/home/ubuntu/.smbcredentials 0  0
```

---

Here's my login.defs content:

```
# /etc/login.defs - Configuration control definitions for the login package.
#
# Three items must be defined:  MAIL_DIR, ENV_SUPATH, and ENV_PATH.
# If unspecified, some arbitrary (and possibly incorrect) value will
# be assumed.  All other items are optional - if not specified then
# the described action or option will be inhibited.
#
# Comment lines (lines beginning with "#") and blank lines are ignored.
#
# Modified for Linux.  --marekm

# REQUIRED for useradd/userdel/usermod
#   Directory where mailboxes reside, _or_ name of file, relative to the
#   home directory.  If you _do_ define MAIL_DIR and MAIL_FILE,
#   MAIL_DIR takes precedence.
#
#   Essentially:
#      - MAIL_DIR defines the location of users mail spool files
#        (for mbox use) by appending the username to MAIL_DIR as defined
#        below.
#      - MAIL_FILE defines the location of the users mail spool files as the
#        fully-qualified filename obtained by prepending the user home
#        directory before $MAIL_FILE
#
# NOTE: This is no more used for setting up users MAIL environment variable
#       which is, starting from shadow 4.0.12-1 in Debian, entirely the
#       job of the pam_mail PAM modules
#       See default PAM configuration files provided for
#       login, su, etc.
#
# This is a temporary situation: setting these variables will soon
# move to /etc/default/useradd and the variables will then be
# no more supported
MAIL_DIR        /var/mail
#MAIL_FILE      .mail

#
# Enable logging and display of /var/log/faillog login failure info.
# This option conflicts with the pam_tally PAM module.
#
FAILLOG_ENAB        yes

#
# Enable display of unknown usernames when login failures are recorded.
#
# WARNING: Unknown usernames may become world readable. 
# See #290803 and #298773 for details about how this could become a security
# concern
LOG_UNKFAIL_ENAB    no

#
# Enable logging of successful logins
#
LOG_OK_LOGINS       no

#
# Enable "syslog" logging of su activity - in addition to sulog file logging.
# SYSLOG_SG_ENAB does the same for newgrp and sg.
#
SYSLOG_SU_ENAB      yes
SYSLOG_SG_ENAB      yes

#
# If defined, all su activity is logged to this file.
#
#SULOG_FILE /var/log/sulog

#
# If defined, file which maps tty line to TERM environment parameter.
# Each line of the file is in a format something like "vt100  tty01".
#
#TTYTYPE_FILE   /etc/ttytype

#
# If defined, login failures will be logged here in a utmp format
# last, when invoked as lastb, will read /var/log/btmp, so...
#
FTMP_FILE   /var/log/btmp

#
# If defined, the command name to display when running "su -".  For
# example, if this is defined as "su" then a "ps" will display the
# command is "-su".  If not defined, then "ps" would display the
# name of the shell actually being run, e.g. something like "-sh".
#
SU_NAME     su

#
# If defined, file which inhibits all the usual chatter during the login
# sequence.  If a full pathname, then hushed mode will be enabled if the
# user's name or shell are found in the file.  If not a full pathname, then
# hushed mode will be enabled if the file exists in the user's home directory.
#
HUSHLOGIN_FILE  .hushlogin
#HUSHLOGIN_FILE /etc/hushlogins

#
# *REQUIRED*  The default PATH settings, for superuser and normal users.
#
# (they are minimal, add the rest in the shell startup files)
ENV_SUPATH  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV_PATH    PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

#
# Terminal permissions
#
#   TTYGROUP    Login tty will be assigned this group ownership.
#   TTYPERM     Login tty will be set to this permission.
#
# If you have a "write" program which is "setgid" to a special group
# which owns the terminals, define TTYGROUP to the group number and
# TTYPERM to 0620.  Otherwise leave TTYGROUP commented out and assign
# TTYPERM to either 622 or 600.
#
# In Debian /usr/bin/bsd-write or similar programs are setgid tty
# However, the default and recommended value for TTYPERM is still 0600
# to not allow anyone to write to anyone else console or terminal

# Users can still allow other people to write them by issuing 
# the "mesg y" command.

TTYGROUP    tty
TTYPERM     0600

#
# Login configuration initializations:
#
#   ERASECHAR   Terminal ERASE character ('\010' = backspace).
#   KILLCHAR    Terminal KILL character ('\025' = CTRL/U).
#   UMASK       Default "umask" value.
#
# The ERASECHAR and KILLCHAR are used only on System V machines.
# 
# UMASK is the default umask value for pam_umask and is used by
# useradd and newusers to set the mode of the new home directories.
# 022 is the "historical" value in Debian for UMASK
# 027, or even 077, could be considered better for privacy
# There is no One True Answer here : each sysadmin must make up his/her
# mind.
#
# If USERGROUPS_ENAB is set to "yes", that will modify this UMASK default value
# for private user groups, i. e. the uid is the same as gid, and username is
# the same as the primary group name: for these, the user permissions will be
# used as group permissions, e. g. 022 will become 002.
#
# Prefix these values with "0" to get octal, "0x" to get hexadecimal.
#
ERASECHAR   0177
KILLCHAR    025
UMASK       000

#
# Password aging controls:
#
#   PASS_MAX_DAYS   Maximum number of days a password may be used.
#   PASS_MIN_DAYS   Minimum number of days allowed between password changes.
#   PASS_WARN_AGE   Number of days warning given before a password expires.
#
PASS_MAX_DAYS   99999
PASS_MIN_DAYS   0
PASS_WARN_AGE   7

#
# Min/max values for automatic uid selection in useradd
#
UID_MIN          1000
UID_MAX         60000
# System accounts
#SYS_UID_MIN          100
#SYS_UID_MAX          999

#
# Min/max values for automatic gid selection in groupadd
#
GID_MIN          1000
GID_MAX         60000
# System accounts
#SYS_GID_MIN          100
#SYS_GID_MAX          999

#
# Max number of login retries if password is bad. This will most likely be
# overriden by PAM, since the default pam_unix module has it's own built
# in of 3 retries. However, this is a safe fallback in case you are using
# an authentication module that does not enforce PAM_MAXTRIES.
#
LOGIN_RETRIES       5

#
# Max time in seconds for login
#
LOGIN_TIMEOUT       60

#
# Which fields may be changed by regular users using chfn - use
# any combination of letters "frwh" (full name, room number, work
# phone, home phone).  If not defined, no changes are allowed.
# For backward compatibility, "yes" = "rwh" and "no" = "frwh".
# 
CHFN_RESTRICT       rwh

#
# Should login be allowed if we can't cd to the home directory?
# Default in no.
#
DEFAULT_HOME    yes

#
# If defined, this command is run when removing a user.
# It should remove any at/cron/print jobs etc. owned by
# the user to be removed (passed as the first argument).
#
#USERDEL_CMD    /usr/sbin/userdel_local

#
# Enable setting of the umask group bits to be the same as owner bits
# (examples: 022 -> 002, 077 -> 007) for non-root users, if the uid is
# the same as gid, and username is the same as the primary group name.
#
# If set to yes, userdel will remove the user´s group if it contains no
# more members, and useradd will create by default a group with the name
# of the user.
#
USERGROUPS_ENAB yes

#
# Instead of the real user shell, the program specified by this parameter
# will be launched, although its visible name (argv[0]) will be the shell's.
# The program may do whatever it wants (logging, additional authentification,
# banner, ...) before running the actual shell.
#
# FAKE_SHELL /bin/fakeshell

#
# If defined, either full pathname of a file containing device names or
# a ":" delimited list of device names.  Root logins will be allowed only
# upon these devices.
#
# This variable is used by login and su.
#
#CONSOLE    /etc/consoles
#CONSOLE    console:tty01:tty02:tty03:tty04

#
# List of groups to add to the user's supplementary group set
# when logging in on the console (as determined by the CONSOLE
# setting).  Default is none.
#
# Use with caution - it is possible for users to gain permanent
# access to these groups, even when not logged in on the console.
# How to do it is left as an exercise for the reader...
#
# This variable is used by login and su.
#
#CONSOLE_GROUPS     floppy:audio:cdrom

#
# If set to "yes", new passwords will be encrypted using the MD5-based
# algorithm compatible with the one used by recent releases of FreeBSD.
# It supports passwords of unlimited length and longer salt strings.
# Set to "no" if you need to copy encrypted passwords to other systems
# which don't understand the new algorithm.  Default is "no".
#
# This variable is deprecated. You should use ENCRYPT_METHOD.
#
#MD5_CRYPT_ENAB no

#
# If set to MD5 , MD5-based algorithm will be used for encrypting password
# If set to SHA256, SHA256-based algorithm will be used for encrypting password
# If set to SHA512, SHA512-based algorithm will be used for encrypting password
# If set to DES, DES-based algorithm will be used for encrypting password (default)
# Overrides the MD5_CRYPT_ENAB option
#
# Note: It is recommended to use a value consistent with
# the PAM modules configuration.
#
ENCRYPT_METHOD SHA512

#
# Only used if ENCRYPT_METHOD is set to SHA256 or SHA512.
#
# Define the number of SHA rounds.
# With a lot of rounds, it is more difficult to brute forcing the password.
# But note also that it more CPU resources will be needed to authenticate
# users.
#
# If not specified, the libc will choose the default number of rounds (5000).
# The values must be inside the 1000-999999999 range.
# If only one of the MIN or MAX values is set, then this value will be used.
# If MIN > MAX, the highest value will be used.
#
# SHA_CRYPT_MIN_ROUNDS 5000
# SHA_CRYPT_MAX_ROUNDS 5000

################# OBSOLETED BY PAM ##############
#                       #
# These options are now handled by PAM. Please  #
# edit the appropriate file in /etc/pam.d/ to   #
# enable the equivelants of them.
#
###############

#MOTD_FILE
#DIALUPS_CHECK_ENAB
#LASTLOG_ENAB
#MAIL_CHECK_ENAB
#OBSCURE_CHECKS_ENAB
#PORTTIME_CHECKS_ENAB
#SU_WHEEL_ONLY
#CRACKLIB_DICTPATH
#PASS_CHANGE_TRIES
#PASS_ALWAYS_WARN
#ENVIRON_FILE
#NOLOGINS_FILE
#ISSUE_FILE
#PASS_MIN_LEN
#PASS_MAX_LEN
#ULIMIT
#ENV_HZ
#CHFN_AUTH
#CHSH_AUTH
#FAIL_DELAY

################# OBSOLETED #######################
#                         #
# These options are no more handled by shadow.    #
#                                                 #
# Shadow utilities will display a warning if they #
# still appear.                                   #
#                                                 #
###################################################

# CLOSE_SESSIONS
# LOGIN_STRING
# NO_PASSWORD_CONSOLE
# QMAIL_DIR
```

Comment: Ps: i can't use the command umask because i can't have access to the software which creates folders and files

Comment: [Did you read this?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions#ACL_.28Access_Control_List.29). Try to set `acl` option via grub and test again. Also, I cannot understand your comment about `umask` . `umask` should fit here as the best solution, but I cannot understand why you can't use it.

Comment: I edited my question and i put the content of my /etc/fstab file. I did this after reading the guide that you linked me in the previous comment.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot see the `acl` option at fstab file. Although I think it's set by default, but I'm not absolutely sure.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking that when ever you create a file or directory those will automatically assign default permissions set by you.

```
umask 000 #put it in .bashrc file
```

- `umask` is inverse of `chmod`.
- `chmod` is used to give permissions.
- `umask` is used to revoke permissions.

`umask 000` means your are giving future files `666` and directories `777` permissions.

by default `022` is assigned, which means `chmod 755`.

Comment: The questioner have already said that S/He cannot use `umask`(for Her/His own reasons).

Comment: Ok, but to use umask i have to put the command in the code which generate the folders and files right ? ... This is the way i know umask can be used. Is there a permanent way ? ... Because i can't put this command in the software that creates folders/files.

Comment: No, tell me what permission you want for your future file or directories.

Comment: @giogix To make changes permanently, you can put the `umask` inside `/etc/profile` and `~/.bashrc` files.

Comment: You can set system-wide umask with /etc/login.def (must be enabled via pam.d). Individual user profiles will still override this setting, as needed.

Comment: Dishank, right now i want full permission for user, group and others (everybody). I know it's not the best thing to do, but is temporary. Nikth yor solution seems good, but in this way am i going to change the default settings for all the folders ? What should i write in profile and bashrc to modify the permissions just in the selected folder ? ... Andrew i didn't really understand yor comment.

Comment: Go to **cat ~/.bashrc**. And write **umask 777** at the end of the line. .bashec file is in home directory.

Comment: Are you sure ? Is it not umask 000 ? I mean, umask is complementary of chmod right ? ... I will do it, but as i told you before this solution is going to change the default settings of all the folders ... but i wanted to do it just for a folder and relative sub-folders.

Comment: It will not do that for your existing files and folders. But if you want to change the permission of existing home directory **chmod -R 777 ~**

Comment: Ok, i did what you suggested me to do. First i have to say that putting the string umask 000 in the end of the **.bashrc** file (in my home directory) didn't affect anything. May be it's about my linux version (which is Ubuntu 14.04). I actually found the default umask command inside of the file **/etc/login.defs**. So i changed the value from **022** to **000**. Then i changed the owner of the folder from root to ubuntu with the **chmod** command (i'm working on a different PC now respect to the first question). Now when i create new folder the permits are **drwxrwxr-x**.

Comment: How can i set default writing permits for the other users ? I mean, i need to have the following configuration **drwxrwxrwx**. Actually i think this is my real problem, i need to have full writing permits for other users, and i don't really care about the group's permits.

Comment: 1) To change owner **chown user-name file-name**. Check the **/etc/login.defs** again there might be a problem with umask. The permissions have to be all to all users. check it again.

Comment: I wrote wrong in my previous comment. I actually have used the chown command, and not the chomd as i wrote. Anyway i put my /etc/login.defs content in a answer, because i can't see anything strange in it. I have to say that i found this file because it was wrote in the /etc/profile one. Could there be another one which also change this kind of configurations ?

Comment: Change the UMASK to umask may be that's the problem.