# Allow a user to inherit permissions of a different user

Tags: permissions, users

I have a problem whereby I have a media app that creates folders and structures (`user1`)  (as a media source). But I have a separate media app that aggregates (`user2`) this and a number of other sources into a collated set of media. When each app installs it creates a new user and group and creates files/folders with that user:group. However I want the media aggregator to be able to manipulate the files/folders of the first app (including deleting files) which it currently cannot do. I also have no option to use a separate user with the problem app.

I have played around with ownership and adding each user to the others group etc but nothing seems to work. The base folder has been given all read/write permissions but these are not inherited to the sub-folders.

I would be very appreciative if someone could help me set this up?

`ls -l` of the folder (I have simplified my list):

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 user2 user2 4096 date folder1
drwxr-xr-x 4 user1 user1 4096 date folder2
```

Note that I want `user2` to be able to manipulate the folder created by `user1`

Comment: Putting both users into the same group and setting the folders and files to be group readable and writeable is all that should be required.  Maybe posting the output from `ls -l` of the troublesome directories would help.  You could also explore the `umask` settings so that the files are created with the required permissions by default, `man umask`

Comment: I tried that ... but I don't want to keep changing the folder folders and files permissions when they are created. I will post `ls -l`

Comment: I edited the post above

Comment: Additionally, I did read: [this link on umask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504192/set-permissions-for-future-folders-and-files?rq=1) but apart from it being a little beyond my knowledge (I could probably use `umask` but not sure I would know what impact it had on other software). I also read that `umask` makes all folders and files permission free and ideally I only want this for this particular base folder.

Comment: You may find the `setgid` property useful: see [Is there any way to make sure that any file created in a specific folder has a certain group as owner?](https://askubuntu.com/q/30491/178692)

Comment: @steeldriver ... I think that is the solution!! I will try a few tests and update accordingly... but very appreciative!

Comment: @Pseudomax it should solve the group ownership part of the problem - you may still need to modify the creating process's `umask` in order to make newly created directories group-writeable. If standard Unix ownership + permissions don't work for your case, the next step is [ACLs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs).

Comment: Hi, yes... I was a bit too optimistic too early! I now have the `group` inherited from the main user (not actually either app created user but my login user for the server). But the actual `user` remains unchanged and that means I am still unable to delete! I have read about ACLs but I only want this base (storage) folder affected by this,  not all future folders created. If you can point me to a beginners tutorial then I can try to fix this ... thank you!!

Comment: For anyone following this or searching for a similar solution, then I believe the following has solved my problem: 'sudo setfacl -R -m user:[my_user]:rwX /my/folder' ... thanks to @steeldriver for pointing me to the right solution...